# Images in top answers section of Careers can show overly large

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

SE sites have max-width CSS property on images in answers. However Careers profiles don't and when answer with large image(s) is selected for "top answers" section it shows in full size and breaks out.

Example in my profile (first and third answers) http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rarst

Comment: That is a cool illustration, man.

Comment: @Pekka thank you! those flowcharts are pretty much my masterpieces and popular references in WP community :)

Comment: What did you use to draw the flowchart?

Comment: @nhahtdh Looks vageuly balsamiq-y (or moqups-y)

Comment: @nhahtdh yep, images done in Balsamiq Mockups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report Rarst. This is fixed now.